# SPSS: Arrange Subtotals in Custom Table

Tags: spss

How do I arrange a subtotal column using SPSS Custom Table?

For example:

```
variable1
Strongly Agree    count1
Agree             count2
Subtotal          count1 + count2
Neutral           count3
Disagree          count4
Strongly Disagree count6
```

I would like to arrange the output like this

```
         Strongly Agree    Agree   Neutral   Disagree    Strongly Disagree    Subtotal
variable1    count1        count2   count3    count4     count5              count1+count2
```

I was able to do arrange it horizontaly but the Subtotal is still after Agree. I want it to be the last column.

Is this possible?

Thanks!

EDIT:

Just solved it by adding a category.

Comment: while creating the custom table  you will see the options for Add Categories ,  then you can get the Net manually by dragging stubs or by selecting the last stub from your sum list and then clicking Add SubTotal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using [`PCOMPUTE`](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSLVMB_21.0.0/com.ibm.spss.statistics.help/syn_ctables_pcompute.htm):

```
GET FILE="C:\Program Files\IBM\SPSS\Statistics\24\Samples\English\Employee data.sav".
CTABLES 
  /VLABELS VARIABLES=jobcat DISPLAY=BOTH 
  /PCOMPUTE &cat1 = EXPR([1]+[2]) 
  /PPROPERTIES &cat1 LABEL = "Cat1&2" FORMAT=COUNT F40.0 HIDESOURCECATS=NO 
  /TABLE jobcat [COUNT F40.0] 
  /CATEGORIES VARIABLES=jobcat [1, 2, 3, &cat1, OTHERNM] EMPTY=INCLUDE.
```